# HTML Canvas: mobile touchmove performance issue

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am making a simple game with HTML Canvas but faced a problem when started testing it on mobile devices.

I want to make drag&drop feature just work, pretty simple task..

[image]

But there is a problem on mobile device: if I listen `touchmove` event and apply touch coordinates to any object on canvas in `requestAnimFrame` method it performs like 5-10FPS, seriously. There is no smooth transition for dragging objects as expected at all.

I made super simple example without any effects, filters and complex math.

https://codepen.io/mctester/pen/bGeGEQq

I use Oneplus 7 Pro for this test (Snapdragon 855, 12GB RAM), but draggable red square in example is very-very laggy.

[image]

This how it looks like if I drag red square from top-left to bottom-right corner with medium speed.

```
/* SAMPLE ONLY FOR MOBILE DEVICE */
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth; //document.width is obsolete
canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight; //document.height is obsolete

var drawing = false;
var mousePos = { x:0, y:0 };
var lastPos = mousePos;

// Set up touch events for mobile, etc
canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function (e) {
   drawing = true;
   mousePos = getTouchPos(canvas, e);
   lastPos = getTouchPos(canvas, e);
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener("touchend", function (e) {
   drawing = false;
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", function (e) {
   mousePos = getTouchPos(canvas, e);
}, false);

// Get the position of a touch relative to the canvas
function getTouchPos(canvasDom, touchEvent) {
   var rect = canvasDom.getBoundingClientRect();
   return {
      x: touchEvent.touches[0].clientX - rect.left,
      y: touchEvent.touches[0].clientY - rect.top
   };
}

// Get a regular interval for drawing to the screen
window.requestAnimFrame = (function (callback) {
      return window.requestAnimationFrame || 
         window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
         window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
         window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
         window.msRequestAnimaitonFrame ||
         function (callback) {
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60);
         };
})();

function animate(currentTime) {
   if (drawing) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
      ctx.rect(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, 10, 10);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();
   }

   requestAnimFrame(animate);
}

requestAnimFrame(animate);
```

How to perform smooth transition of objects with `touchmove` event for drag&drop feature in HTML Canvas?

Comment: Well, your device has a relatively high display resolution but: 1) Did you try lowering the size of the canvas? 2) Does this happen on any browser? 3) Did you test this code as 'pure' html - thus without all the codepen stuff that's probably working in the background?

Comment: @obscure thanks for answer. 1) actually, canvas is not so big for such behavior. 2) I've tested it on multiple android devices with different screen resolution but result is the same. 3) yes, I've tested it on my own blank hosting - same result.